# Uploading an XML file to a s3 bucket with boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to upload an XML file to a s3 bucket with AWS with a lambda function and a HTTP request. The principal problem is that I am not able to convert the XML file passed by the body of the HTTP request.

```
import json
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = 'xmlresultmarco'
    
    fileName = 'Test'+'.xml'
    
    uploadByteStream = event

    try:
        s3.put_object(Bucket = bucket, Key = fileName, Body = uploadByteStream )
        return "Upload completed"
    
    except Exception as e:
        return e
        raise e
```

Is there someone that can help me?

Comment: `event` is not a byte stream. You can't just do `uploadByteStream = event` and magically convert it to a byte stream by virtue of the variable name. Your current problem statement says you are not able to convert the XML file passed in the body, but the code in your question shows no attempt to convert anything. As always, your first step should be to add some logs to see what you are working with. I would log the entire `event` object, and then look at what is actually in that object.

Comment: Where are you expecting the content of the XML file to come from? How is the Lambda function being triggered with this XML file?

Comment: with an HTTP request and the XML code is in the body of the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code to get you started.

The lambda function definition might look something like this.

```
def download_lambda(event, context):
    url = event['url']
    bucket = event['bucket_name']
    key = event['key']
    download_url(url, bucket_name=bucket, key=key)
```

Then the download function might look like this.  I use multi-part to cater for large files.

```
def download_url(url, bucket_name, key):
    response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    response.raise_for_status()
    assert response.status_code == 200
    obj = s3.Object(bucket_name, key)
    multi_part_upload = obj.initiate_multipart_upload()
    partNo = 1
    parts = []
    default_chunk_size = 1024*1024*10 # Must be at least 5mb
    for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=default_chunk_size):
        if chunk:
            part = multi_part_upload.Part(partNo)
            response = part.upload(Body=chunk)
            parts.append({
                'PartNumber': partNo,
                'ETag': response['ETag']
            })
            partNo += 1
    part_info = {}
    part_info['Parts'] = parts
    multi_part_upload.complete(MultipartUpload=part_info)
```

Clearly I am not dealing with any XML conversion here, per Mark's point.  You will need to figure that out when you read the file.